# Best way to remove (not pop) last/rightmost object occurrence from a stack using collections.deque

Tags: python, queue, stack

I am using the standard `collections.deque` to write a LIFO stack where each object may occur multiple times, but now I am cornered around the use case for removing the **last occurrence of a given object** (but not whatever is the rightmost object of the stack!).

While `appendleft`, `extendleft` and `popleft` counterparts exist for these three methods, no `removeright` (nor `indexright`) exist. So the following is not possible.

```py
import collections

stack = collections.deque()

a = object()
b = object()
c = object()

stack.append(a)
stack.append(b)
stack.append(c)
stack.append(a)
stack.append(b)
stack.append(c)

list(stack) # [a, b, c, a, b, c]

stack.removeright(b)  # Fat chance

list(stack)  # Whish: [a, b, c, a, c] and *NOT* [a, c, a, b, c]
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Right now I am going with a double reverse call like

```py
def removeright(stack, item):
    stack.reverse()
    try:
        stack.remove(item)
    finally:
        stack.reverse()
```

but this feels wrong. I am worried about both inefficiency and potential pitfalls down the road for this approach.

I could always use the queue "backwards" (actually quite conventional), using `appendleft` and `remove`, but I'd like to retain the "append" semantics and still not have to write a thin wrapper patching every right/left stack method to a left/right queue method.

Would someone share their insights/experience on the subject?

Comment: There is no *queue* class in the *collections* module

Comment: `collections.deque`, sorry!

Comment: Already fixed the question

Comment: A call to yourDeque.pop() is equivalent to "remove right"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can't come up with a simple solution to this problem, I now believe **a little semantics sacrifice is worth it** and just use the `collections.deque` object "backwards".

Simply put: consider the "left" end to be the "top" of the stack.

Bonus 1: when not popping the stack iterates naturally in a LIFO order

Bonus 2: for the probable case when the removed object is close to the last position (now "leftmost"), CPython's deque.remove will perform the smallest rotation of the internal datastructure. Up to no operation at all when removing the very last item. So this should be blazing fast. Screw lists!

```
import collections

stack = collections.deque()

stack.appendleft("a")
stack.appendleft("b")
stack.appendleft("c")
stack.appendleft("a")
stack.appendleft("b")
stack.appendleft("c")

list(stack)  # [c, b, a, c, b, a]

stack.remove("b")

def consume():
    while stack:
        yield stack.popleft()

list(consume())  # yields [c, a, c, b, a]
```

Drawback: the issue is reverted as there is no simple formula for removal of the *first* (now "rightmost") occurrence of a given object in the deque. Therefore, using the deque objects with this "reversed semantics" should be conditioned to whether your removing/indexing use-case is for either the last or the first occurrence of a stack.

For a general solution, keep reading.

---

If you are really into removing the rightmost occurrence in a deque object.

It turns out `deque.remove` is internally implemented with a double rotation until the desired item is at an end, when it is popped and then the deque object is rotated back into the original state. This is a CPython implementation detail, though. See

- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ee821dcd3961efc47262322848267fe398faa4e4/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L1249
- https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ee821dcd3961efc47262322848267fe398faa4e4/Modules/_collectionsmodule.c#L1200

So a consistent and efficient solution might be a matter of iteratively finding the last index of a multiply present object and also doing a double rotation instead of a double reversion.

For my use case, the item to be removed will quite often be the actual last item of the whole stack. So the following implementation favors rotating as few positions as possible, up to the corner case of rotating none and only popping from the right.

Also, it is nice to retain the ValueError being raised in absence of the item, thus the unavoidable `deque.index` call.

```
def index_right(stack, item):
    idx = stack.index(item)
    for _ in range(1, stack.count(item)):
        idx = stack.index(item, idx + 1)
    return idx

def remove_right(stack, item):
    rot = len(stack) - index_right(stack, item) - 1
    d.rotate(rot)
    try:
        d.pop()
    finally:
        d.rotate(-rot)
```

A drawback is: for a big stack this may take a lot of unnecessary value comparisons because `deque.index` operates from left to right and the searched items will usually be at the end. So, the revert-remove-revert solution from the original question might still outperform this answer under certain conditions.

Answer (score 0):

The only other way I could find would be to start from the last position and decrement until you find the item you're looking for.

```py
def for_remove(stack, s):
    # Optionally check if the element is in the stack first
    if s not in stack:
        return

    for i in range(len(stack)-1, -1, -1):
        if s == stack[i]:
            del stack[i]
            break
```

Although this avoids two reversal operations, you are still having to loop through your deque in Python. Although clunky, your solution has the advantage of using speed-optimised, compiled, methods and is most likely faster than the above solution.

The question is: is this level of optimisation warranted for your current task? Do you need to be shaving off microseconds from the deletion time? In most cases, your containers will be small enough that any optimizations have a negligble impact on the runtime.

Comment: Yet this is fundamentally a good idea. With only a smart use of deque.index so that the more performant CPython implementation finds the occurrence should have a good efficiency. Fun fact, that `del stack[i]` instruction will actually rotate that position to the left and then pop it (and unrotate the deque back to the previous start/end).